# Not able to install the latest termcolor version

Tags: tensorflow, termcolor

I am trying to install termcolor version 1.1.0, so that i can further install Tensorflow, as there's a dependency, but unable to install the latest termcolor.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement termcolor==1.1.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for termcolor==1.1.0
```

Currently, my termcolor version is 0.2

I tried several ways like --upgrade, but no luck..

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `termcolor` using below code, it will install the latest version of termcolor which is 1.1.0.:

```
!pip install termcolor
```

However, If you install `TensorFlow` using pip, it will automatically install some required package along with `TensorFlow` which also includes `termcolor` module.

```
!pip install tensorflow
```